# How can I force a meteor app to make all HTTP calls through a proxy?

Tags: proxy, meteor

I'm trying to emulate [curl through a proxy server](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). The [meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#http) don't mention any proxy settings for HTTP.* methods.

Is there a meteor-specific solution? Right now I'm using [ProxyChains](https://github.com/haad/proxychains).

Ideally I'd use a SOCKS proxy and only HTTP.* calls would go through it, but I'm open to all calls from the application going through any type of proxy.

Comment: Do you mean you want all HTTP calls to go through a proxy or just the ones you specify with HTTP.call/get/post also anything specific Do you have SOCKS in mind or a HTTP type proxy ? I guess if its HTTP you could alter a couple of headers. Socks lets get through Tor if thats what you wanted?

Comment: @Tarang: SOCKS, and HTTP.* calls. I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Meteor 1.1 update

You can pass options directly to the [npm request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) via the `npmRequestOptions` parameter to [HTTP.*](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call). The functionality was enabled by [this commit](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/8dae78d48b80d7dab9154d912102a9ebb0a28f60) made after I filed an issue in 2013 (see below).

You no longer need to use the http-more package.

### Old answer, pre-Meteor 1.1

One method would be pass a `proxy` parameter to `HTTP.*` calls, which use the [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request#requestoptions-callback), which supports proxies as an option.

`proxy` isn't a recognized option in the HTTP package, and [I've filed a request to simply pass through unrecognized options. It was rejected by one of the Meteor core developers.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1703)

I'd rather people vote on that issue, asking for unknown options to be passed through instead of being ignored. In the meantime, I've created a package that does pass through options: [http-more](https://atmospherejs.com/dandv/http-more).

Comment: Thanks for this @Dan this sounds awesome and exactly what I need. However, I didn't really understand how to use your package - can you give a dummy's example of how to configure my Meteor server to use a proxy?

Comment: Also, is it possible to configure to use proxy one-time (i.e. only one call) but not for others?

Comment: @Alveoli: turns out that in the meantime MDG implemented my feature request to pass options to the `request` module. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Meteor proxy package: https://npmjs.org/package/seafish-http-proxy-meteor

It's not available through atmosphere, but it is an npm package designed for meteor, which means it will be very easy to integrate.

Comment: In the meantime MDG has implemented my feature request to pass options to the `request` module. I've updated my answer above. The seafish proxy package hasn't been updated since November 2013.