# How do I make meteor server HTTP.call through proxy?

Tags: meteor

My meteor server will fetch data from another source on Internet. The request has to go via a proxy. How can I specify the proxy server for server-side HTTP.call's?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I force a Meteor app to make all HTTP calls through a proxy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040953/how-can-i-force-a-meteor-app-to-make-all-http-calls-through-a-proxy) (I've asked this question myself :) Though SO is surprisingly bad at finding it as related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for my problem.

I'm using Windows and could not find a way to set a default proxy for the OS as Serkan mentioned. Setting proxy server in Internet Explorer internet options LAN settings did not work. Settings proxy in winHTTP did not work. Anyone else know how to do it?

The most reasonable would be that Node read a environment variable and used that. So, I created an environment variable "HTTP_PROXY" and to see if node would read it I tried:

```
D:\Appl\.meteor\tools\a5dc07c9ab\bin>node -e "console.log(process.env.http_proxy)"
```

and it did output my variable. But, when trying to make a http.get() request directly within Node it failed. Node is obviously not using that variable ...

The conclusion of that is that I have to explicitly set the proxy in my app, but that is not possible with Meteor HTTP. Instead I could use the request module (that Meteor HTTP is using) and set the proxy. Not the ideal solution, because my app has to know about the proxy, but ok for my purpose.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var request = Npm.require("request");
    var makeRequest = Meteor._wrapAsync(thirdLibMakeRequest);
    function thirdLibMakeRequest(options, callback) {
        options.proxy = "http://myProxyServer:8080";
        request(options, callback);
    };
    var response = makeRequest({ url: "http://UrlToSomeSite" });
}
```

- Include the request module
- Wrap the 3rd-lib async method so we can use it in Meteor
- set the proxy property of the request module
- use makeRequest to make requests.

Comment: In the meantime I've [published a package](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22069540/1269037) that should allow you to pass options to Node's `request` module.

Answer (score 6):

You could easily make all `HTTP.*` calls through a proxy if only Meteor developers accepted my pull request to pass through options like `proxy` to the `request` module, on which the `HTTP` package is based.

[Please comment on this GitHub issue to ask for that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040953/how-can-i-force-a-meteor-app-to-make-all-http-calls-through-a-proxy/22069488#22069488)

UPDATE: Since the Meteor devs refused to implement that change, I published an Atmosphere package that lets you transmit to Node (i.e. to the `request` module) any options you want.

Check out **[http-more](https://atmospherejs.com/dandv/http-more)** on Atmosphere.

Comment: Can you give us an example of how to use http-more to set a proxy server with a meteor project ?

Comment: @Andrew: I haven't used proxies myself, but [others have](https://github.com/StockBase/meteor-http-more/pull/3). The syntax is the same as the one for the [request module](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback): simply add `proxy` to the [http options](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http) object.

Answer (score -1):

Since the platform your meteor app will be running on will be behind the proxy as a whole, you'll be needing proxy access generally anyway.

Therefore, you can set your platform (os) up to connect to the proxy server by default, therefore Meteor will not necessarily know/care about the presence of a proxy since it will be transparent to it.

Comment: I've [published a module](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22069540/1269037) that allows passing parameters to Node's `request` module, including proxy. That way only the meteor app needs to go through the proxy.